# Monkey patch module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching, rails-i18n

I want to alter I18n.translate method in existing project.

```
require 'I18n'
module I18n
  alias_method :old_translate, :translate
  def translate(*args)
    old_translate(*args) + 'blabla'
  end
  alias_method :t, :translate
end
```

This generates:

> Uncaught exception: Missing helper file helpers/I18n.rb

What I do wrong and where I should put this code?

Comment: do you mean `require 'i18n'` ? beware the case sensitivity.

Comment: After changing this, I get: 
Uncaught exception: undefined method `translate' for module `I18n'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  wtfblabla: hello
```

test.rb:

```
require 'i18n'
module I18n
  class<< self
    alias_method :old_translate, :translate
    def translate(*args)
      old_translate(*args) + 'blabla'
    end
    alias_method :t, :translate
  end
end

I18n.load_path += p(Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'locales', '*.yml').to_s])

p I18n.t "wtfblabla"
```

output:

> ["./config/locales/en.yml"]
>
> "helloblabla"

Comment: module methods are "static" (i.e. need to start with self), since they aren't tied to an instance. That's why I put your monkey patch in a self block.

Comment: This is a nice answer. If you use `alias_method_chain` you need only one declaration. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.15/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain)